# Simple php contact form script only works sporadically

Tags: php, html

I receive the email about 50% of the time, but I can't work out what the differentiates the successful ones from the unsuccessful ones. Web page always returns "Your Message was sent Successfully!"

Contact Form:

```
    <?php include "sendmail.php"; ?>
    <!doctype html>




    <form class="mb-5" method="post">
    <div class="row"><div class="col-md-6 form-group mb-3">
    <label for="" class="col-form-label">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group mb-3">
    <label for="" class="col-form-label">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"  placeholder="Your email">
    </div></div>
    <div class="row"><div class="col-md-6 form-group mb-3">
    <label for="" class="col-form-label">Phone:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Your phone number">
    </div><div class="col-md-6 form-group mb-3">
    <label for="" class="col-form-label">Sex:</label>
    <input type="radio" id="male" name="sex" value="male"><label for="sex">Male</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="sex" value="female">
    <label for="female">Female</label><br>
    </div></div>
    <div class="row mb-5">
    <div class="col-md-12 form-group mb-3">
    <label for="experience" class="col-form-label">Relevant Experience/Any other information</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="experience" id="experience" cols="30" rows="4"  placeholder="Write your message"></textarea>
    </div></div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center"><div class="col-md-5 form-group text-center">
    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary rounded-0 py-2 px-4">
    <span class="submitting"></span></div></div>
```

sendmail.php

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $to = "example@gmail.com"; // My email address
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $from = $_POST['email'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $sex = $_POST['sex'];
        $experience = $_POST['experience'];
        $subject = "Contact Form Details";
        $headers = "From:" . $from;
        $MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$name."\n"; 
        $MESSAGE_BODY .= "email: ".$email."\n"; 
        $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Phone: ".$phone."\n"; 
        $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Sex: ".$sex."\n"; 
        $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Experience: ".$experience."\n"; 
    
        $result = mail($to,$subject,$MESSAGE_BODY,$headers);

        if ($result) {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Your Message was sent Successfully!");</script>';
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = window.location.href;</script>';

        }else{
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Sorry! Message was not sent, Try again Later.");</script>';
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = window.location.href;</script>';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

About half the time mail won't be received, I've checked spam folders etc.

I repeat myself, but as I said above I receive the email about 50% of the time, but I can't work out what the differentiates the successful ones from the unsuccessful ones. Web page always returns "Your Message was sent Successfully!"

Comment: It's quite likely that your email is being blocked en route. Work through all the points listed in the answers to the linked question, expecially SPF, DKIM and DMARC and verify that they have all been addressed before asking for more help.

Comment: Allowing the user to specify the From field of the email is a mistake too. To other webservers, your message now looks like an attempt to impersonate someone else's email account. Use a fixed From address which is on the same domain as the mailserver

Comment: If you send lots of emails, you should consider to use queues and send them with a worker. Then you can retry the failed, again. It also may be helpful to use a specialized mass sending service.